# Ember Data does not allow duplicate entries in hasMany relationships

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have the following model:

```
#order/model.coffee
Order = DS.Model.extend {
  line_items: DS.hasMany 'product', {async: true}
}
```

At some point I want to add the some products to the order. I found that I can only add the product once, adding the same product again does not work:

```
#product/route.coffee
...
actions:
    # Not actually my code but illustrates the problem
    addToCart: (product1, product2)->
      order = @modelFor 'order'
      console.log order.get('line_items.length') # prints 0

      order.get('line_items').pushObject product1
      console.log order.get('line_items.length') # prints 1

      order.get('line_items').pushObject product2
      console.log order.get('line_items.length') # prints 2

      order.get('line_items').pushObject product1
      console.log order.get('line_items.length') # prints 2

      order.get('line_items').pushObject product2
      console.log order.get('line_items.length') # prints 2


      ...
```

The problem is that the user might want a single item more than once. The simplest way to represent that is to have an array with duplicate entries. It seems Ember is not letting me do that for relationships. How can I add a model more than once to a relationship ?

Comment: Should be hasMany('product'), not 'products'

Comment: Also, which order are you trying to add to? You should either create a new order, or retrieve one from the store, modify it, and save it back. You have to at least create a new order. Your addToCart action only has knowledge of of a product, but not of order

Comment: I think you are checking the length of the DS attribute declaration, and not of the length of an array

Comment: @ChristopherMilne, fixed the 'products' to 'product' with the same results. I have omitted where the order comes from for brevity, but it is an existing order retrieved from the server elsewhere. I am pretty sure I am checking the actual array. Either way, the array that gets serialized to JSON only contains one item.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with an ember data relationship? If this is an e-commerce site, and the user completes an order, and a year from now you pull the record for the order and the product models have changed, will the order be accurate?

Comment: I keep an array of changes on the products so you can always reconstruct it to the state it was in. So yes. But that's not the point of this question.

Comment: The "line items" model below is the right solution. If you don't want a quantity field, you could have OrderItem without quantity and just repeat OrderItems for the same product. Then you have a toMany relation to orderitems and each will be unique even if representing the same product.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you actually need a `line_items` model with a quantity field. Just shoving more of the same item in your `orders` model isn't really a normalized solution.

I would recommend the following:

```
lineItem = DS.Model.extend({
    orders: DS.belongsTo('orders'),
    product: DS.belongsTo('products'),
    quantity: DS.attr('number'),
});

orders = DS.Model.extend({
    lineItems: DS.hasMany('lineItem', {async: true}),
    customerId: DS.belongsTo('customers'),
});

products = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    cost: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

This would allow you to create multiple records in your lineItem model, that will have a unique ID but be bound to a specific order, (which would solve the issue of multiple orders having the same lineItem) for example, you could have:

```
{
    "lineItem" : 
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "orderId": 1,
                "product": 1,
                "quantity": 100,
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "orderId": 1,
                "product": 2,
                "quantity": 10,
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "orderId": 2,
                "product": 1,
                "quantity": 100,
            }
        ]
}
```

In this design you would remove the reference to lineItems from your json, as ember-data looks after the inverse relationship for you (if you aren't [sideloading](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships) the relationship you will need to add async to your model). This will mean that if you need to change a line item, it will only affect one order, and if you need to change the order that a lineItem is related to you just do this on the lineItem model.

```
{
    "Orders" : 
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "customerId": 123456,
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "customerId": 123456,
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: My problem with that is that I need to build server side support for a lineItem model (something that generates a unique ID for each line Item, otherwise Ember Data will get confused). This is a huge overhead for something that should be very simple. I wish there was a way to have ID-less embedded relationships.

Comment: To have a record repeated in your model in the db would be a many-to-many relationship. This isn't normalized and is why ember won't like you doing it. As far as I can see the adding the lineitem model is the normalized way to go. It makes most sense from the point of view of future queries. For example if you wanted to know the most popular product. Just total the quantities for lineitems containing the product id.

Comment: This is indeed a many to many relationship as orders have many products and products can be in many orders. So would you design your backend with a separate endpoint `/line-items` that allows CRUD method? Then several orders would be allowed to share the same line-items, which makes no sense, as modifying it somewhere would modify all orders.

Comment: You make a good point with regards to the CRUD endpoint. I have updated the answer to handle this.

Comment: I see what you mean but I still find the overhead of this solution huge (separate table, separate CRUD endpoints for the new model). To top it off, I am using a NoSQL DB, so embedding subdocuments is the natural approach for me. Unfortunately, Ember Data still seems very RAILS + SQL centric.

Comment: Yeh, I think you're right that ember as a is currently more geared to relational, normalized models, and although you use a noSQL backend, there's no reason why you can't structure your api in this way. It depends on what you want to do on the front-end and if these relationships would be of any use to you. If not and you just want embedded id-less models, I have had some success with [model fragments](https://github.com/lytics/ember-data.model-fragments), which i discovered from [this](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/53#issuecomment-95988694) github issue.

Answer (score 1):

They should have an `id` property, then they will be able to co-exist in the same array and be distinct items of the same product type - with the same name (all the same properties other than `id`).

Either that, or you have one record that represents a product type, and then have a `quantity` attribute to specify how many of each product there are..

Comment: This answer is actual better fit as a comment to the question. It does not answer the question, you simply ask for more clarification.

Comment: The answer is: it should have an `id` attribute to differentiate between the items.. the questions were more me thinking outloud (perhaps that was not needed.)

Comment: I have an ID property, and I still get the same issue. The with the quantity approach is that it breaks the simple model Ember Data likes in many ways. I need to have a separate model just for quantity/product topples. I like the array approach because it's much simpler.

Comment: after thinking about this some moew.. If you have a `lineitem` model with a `product` belongsTo property.. then you can create a new record (with individual `id` attribute) for every line item, but the product can be the same single product model.